# Bitwise AND in Java Hashtable hash lookups?

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashtable, bit-manipulation

I noticed that the [hash function code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Hashtable.java#Hashtable.get%28java.lang.Object%29) as part of `java.util.Hashtable#get(K key)` does the following: `int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;`. Is this binary 'and' operation meant only to reset the sign bit? and therefore avoid negative table access.

UPDATE: the fact that they 'and' with a 0x7FFFFFFF and not a 0xEFFFFFFF puzzled me. Why does the sign requires a full byte rather than a single bit?

Comment: The index mus be positive and by clearing the highest bit it is sure that the value is positive. And will be positive after `%`.

Comment: Your update puzzles me. Both 0xE and 0x7 have a single bit unset. The only difference is which bit is unset: E is 1110 (so the fourth most significant bit is unset), while 7 is 0111 (so the most significant bit is unset). The sign bit is the most significant bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  This is to avoid negative indexing into the underlying array in the hash table.

Note that in languages with unsigned integer types like C or C++ this could be avoided by just using unsigned values in the hash function.

**EDIT:** Given your new question about why `0x7FFFFFF` versus `0xEFFFFFF` - the first of these numbers is all 1s with the top bit set to 0.  The second of these does not have this property; it comes out to `1110` followed by lots of 1s.  Therefore, masking with the first will clear the 1 bit, while masking with the second might not do this.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

> the fact that they 'and' with a 0x7FFFFFFF and not a 0xEFFFFFFF puzzled me. Why does the sign requires a full byte rather than a single bit?

0x7FFFFFFF is just the top bit. In binary it is 01111111111111111111111111111111. Where as 0xEFFFFFFF is 11101111111111111111111111111111 so it would mask out a different bit.